# how to run the music background in website continuously

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have written the following code, where every time when I open new page the music will start from the beginning. Please help me out.

```
<body>
<embed src="2.mp3" autostart="true" loop="infinite"
width="2" height="0">
</embed>
---
---
</body>
```

Comment: Word of advice: Doing this will likely annoy a good percentage of your visitors. You can use `<audio>` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio

Comment: There is no code in your question, just markup. Please post your code.

Comment: Agree with techfoobar - This is an absolutely terrible idea and most people will dislike it.  Unless this is an absolute requirement from your superiors, I would nix the idea.

Answer (score 2):

The below will keep playing a background sountrack:

```
<audio src="2.mp3" autoplay loop></audio>
```

Comment: @Ramya it should work perfectly , just let me know what issue you are facing

Comment: @Ramya tested and works now , i forgot to add autoplay hence the audio didnt play on load

Comment: The problem is, when I navigate from one page to another music will start form the beginning, since I have written the same code in all the pages.how can I resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

Embed the audio tag and set the autoplay and loop attribute. Try this:

```
<audio src="http://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3" style="display: none" autoplay loop>
```

Comment: how did you declare the html doctype? declare the HTML version of your doctype as <!DOCTYPE html>. You can check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/erL7h7cv/

Comment: The problem is, when I navigate from one page to another music will start form the beginning, since I have written the same code in all the pages.how can I resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks All. I found the code for it.

```js
<script>

function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
{
    var exdate=new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
    var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
    document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

function getCookie(c_name)
{
    var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
    for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++)
    {
      x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
      y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
      x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
      if (x==c_name)
        {
        return unescape(y);
        }
      }
}

var song = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0];
var played = false;
var tillPlayed = getCookie('timePlayed');
function update()
{
    if(!played){
        if(tillPlayed){
        song.currentTime = tillPlayed;
        song.play();
        played = true;
        }
        else {
                song.play();
                played = true;
        }
    }

    else {
    setCookie('timePlayed', song.currentTime);
    }
}
setInterval(update,1000);
</script>
```

```html
<audio preload="auto" src="http://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3" loop="true" autobuffer>

</audio>
```